# How to implement merge sort without recursion

Tags: java, iteration, mergesort

The arrays are always the size of powers of 2, and it can't be recursive.

If I've made any errors in asking my question this is my first time asking a question. Bear with me please.

The plan is to place markers in powers of two then loop through and place the ordered numbers into an array then putting them back in the array. Then should be placed into the original array in the groups that they were placed split into. Gradually getting bigger until the whole array is sorted.

```
public static void MergeSortNonRec(long[] a) {
    //======================
    //FILL IN YOUR CODE HERE
    //======================    

    System.out.println(a.length);  // print statement
    if (a == null) 
        return;
    int subArray1 = 0;
    int subArray2 = 1;
    int increment = 0;

    int swapCounter = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= a.length; i *= 2) {
        // this loop determines the current size of the sub array
        increment = i;
        subArray1 = 0;
        subArray2 = 0;
        swapCounter = 0;

        while (subArray2 <= a.length) {
            // this will loop until we reach the end of the array

            subArray2 += increment;

            long[] spareArray = new long[2 * i];
            swapCounter = 0;
            while (swapCounter <= spareArray.length) {
                System.out.println(subArray1 + " " + subArray2); // print statement
                if (a[subArray1] < a[subArray2]) {
                    spareArray[swapCounter] = a[subArray1];
                    swapCounter++;
                    subArray1++;
                } else
                if (a[subArray1] > a[subArray2]) {
                    spareArray[swapCounter] = a[subArray2];
                    swapCounter++;
                    subArray2++;
                } else
                if (a[subArray1] == a[subArray2]) {
                    spareArray[swapCounter] = a[subArray1];
                    swapCounter++;
                    subArray1++;
                    System.out.println(swapCounter + " " + subArray1); // print statement
                    spareArray[swapCounter] = a[subArray1];
                    swapCounter++;
                    subArray2++;
                }
            } // this creates an array of the ordered elements 

            while (swapCounter == spareArray.length) {
                subArray1 -= swapCounter / 2;
                subArray2 -= swapCounter / 2;
                // now the sub array pointers are back to the values they started at
                int spareArrayPointer = 0;
                for (; subArray1 <= subArray2; subArray1++) {
                    a[subArray1] = spareArray[spareArrayPointer];
                    spareArrayPointer++;
                } // this places the values in the spare array into the original array
                subArray1 -= spareArrayPointer;
                spareArrayPointer = 0;
                // takes the first pointer back to where it started
            }
            subArray1 += increment;
            subArray2 += increment + increment;
        } // end subArray2 <= a.length loop
    } // end 2*i loop
} //MergeSortNonRec()
```

Comment: All recursion can be unrolled as a loop, and an algorithm as old and common as merge-sort has _maaaaany_ articles written about how to implement it using just a for or while loop already. Web searching should yield plenty of results

Answer (score 4):

A non-recursive implementation of merge sort could still be based on top down merge sort, using a stack to push and pop pairs of indexes.

A more common implementation of non-recursive merge sort is bottom up, where an array of n elements is treated as n "sorted" runs of size 1 (since their size is 1, they can be considered sorted), then for each merge "pass", merge even and odd runs, which doubles the run size on each pass. Repeat until run size >= array size.

Wiki example. This example could be optimized by swapping A and B after each pass to change the direction of merge with each pass and avoid the copy back except for the lass pass (or determine number of passes in advance, and swap in place to start with run size = 2 before doing the merge passes).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation